# IOException access denied when Directory.Move subfolder and parent folder

Tags: c#, ioexception, .net

I am trying to rename multiple folders that have subfolders, but when I use Directory.Move() on a subfolder the parent folder seem to get locked up.

My code:

```
var pathParent = @"D:\test\f1";
var pathSub = @"D:\test\f1\f2";

var pathParentnew = @"D:\test\f1new";
var pathSubnew = @"D:\test\f1\f2new";

Directory.Move(pathSub, pathSubnew);
Directory.Move(pathParent, pathParentnew);
```

The last `Directory.Move(`) throws an

> IOException: Access to "D:\test\f1" is denied

Does anyone know how I can rename both folders?

Comment: Do you have already folder called `D:\test\f1new` ?

Comment: No, I do not. Tnx for the edit.

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly in my machine.

Comment: Are you sure you don't nothing between this codes?

Comment: Actually, it worked the first time I ran it. If I rename the folders back to the original names and run it again, it throws the exception.

Comment: Funny but I tried also what you say. First time it works, I renamed folders back to the original names, then I run, and still works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to close File Explorer in Windows. The process was locking up the folders somehow.

Comment: That's strange, a PARENT folder was opened for my case and that was the locking issue...

Answer (score 0):

Your program has previously opened a file in the parent directory. You need to close that file stream before it will let you rename the folder.

Comment: Tnx for he reply. Do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
 DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(oldpath);
 dirInfo.MoveTo(newPath);
```