# Directory.Move fails while copying files 1 by 1 works

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, hosted on IIS 8, windows server 2012 and I upload some files to a temporary directory. After doing some other work, all these files are moved to a concrete directory. My question is why doesn't `Directory.Move` work while `FileInfo.CopyTo` works.

`Directory.Move` fails with

> "Access to the path 'serverPath...' is denied."

Code I'm using to move entire directory:

```
 var pathFrom = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Objects/" + tempFolderName); //tempFolderName is a random generated GUID.
 var pathTo = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Objects/" + ObjectId); //ObjectId is an integer
 if (Directory.Exists(pathFrom))
     {
       Directory.Move(pathFrom, pathTo);
     }
```

To create a temporary directory I'm simply calling:  `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` which works and creates the temporary directory, and files are saved inside it.

Method I use to copy files, one by one, which works:

```
public static void DirectoryCopy(string strSource, string Copy_dest)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strSource);

            DirectoryInfo[] directories = dirInfo.GetDirectories();

            FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo tempdir in directories)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strSource + "/" + tempdir);

                Directory.CreateDirectory(Copy_dest + "/" + tempdir.Name);// creating the Directory   

                var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(tempdir.Name);

                if (System.IO.Path.HasExtension(ext))
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo tempfile in files)
                    {
                        tempfile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(strSource + "/" + tempfile.Name, Copy_dest + "/" + tempfile.Name));

                    }
                }
                DirectoryCopy(strSource + "/" + tempdir.Name, Copy_dest + "/" + tempdir.Name);

            }

            FileInfo[] files1 = dirInfo.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo tempfile in files1)
            {
                tempfile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(Copy_dest, tempfile.Name));

            }
        }
```

What I tried to make `Directory.Move` work:

1. Checked to see if directory `pathTo` doesn't exist
2. Checked to see if IIS has required permissions: `IISAppPool/DefaultAppPool` has full access to the Uploads folder.
3. Tried to check with Process monitor if any other error comes up but it seems that this doesn't even get logged.
4. Closed every explorer.

Can anyone explain why `Directory.Move` doesn't work (with the access deny error) while moving the files one by one works?

Does `Directory.Move` require more privileges than just copying files 1 by 1?
Please be aware that the application is not under wwwroot... but on other drive.

Pages I already read:

[Why am I still getting "Access to the path 'C:\...\...' is denied" even after granting IIS_IUSRS write permission on the directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292148/why-am-i-still-getting-access-to-the-path-c-is-denied-even-after-gr)

[Access to path denied on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717820/access-to-path-denied-on-iis)

[IOException access denied when Directory.Move subfolder and parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002085/ioexception-access-denied-when-directory-move-subfolder-and-parent-folder)

**EDIT**
After copying the files using `FileInfo.Copy` I delete the tempFolder with `Directory.Delete(pathFrom, true);` which also works.

Comment: if something feels theres an item in that folder structure in use, it wont move it, this can be a command prompt, file explorer, antivirus, actual application..

Comment: I tried to use Process monitor to check if anything from that folder is used, but no process is using that folder (`Objects/tempFolderName`) or anything from it

Comment: do you have delete permissions on the parent folder to the folder you're trying to move eg say its c:\temp\myfolder you wish to move, do you have delete rights on c:\temp?

Comment: @BugFinder I granted full control to the application folder (root folder) and set to apply the same rules to any subfolders/files.